# Pandas isin boolean operator giving error

Tags: pandas

I am running into an error while using the 'isin' Boolean operator:

```
def rowcheck(row):
 return row['CUST_NAME'].isin(['John','Alan'])
```

My dataframe has column CUST_NAME. So I use:

```
df['CUSTNAME_CHK'] = df.apply (lambda row: rowcheck(row),axis=1)
```

I get:

`'str' object has no attribute 'isin'`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you are using `.apply`, then `row` is a `pd.Series`, and `row['CUST_NAME']` will be whatever value is at that index in the series, in your case, presumably a string. Likely, you don't need apply at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it inside a function passed to apply, such that `row['CUST_NAME']` holds the value for a specific cell (and it is a string). Strings which have no `isin` method. This method belongs to `pd.Series`, and not strings.

If you really want to use `apply`, use `np.isin` in this case

```
def rowcheck(row): 
    return pd.np.isin(row['CUST_NAME'], ['John','Alan'])
```

As @juanpa.arrivilaga noticed, `isin` won't be efficient in this case, so its advised to use the operator `in` directly

```
return row['CUST_NAME'] in ['John','Alan']
```

Notice that you probably don't need `apply`. You can just use `pd.Series.isin`directly. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'dfe']})


col1
0   abc
1   dfe
```

Such that you can do

```
df.col1.isin(['abc', 'xyz'])

0     True
1    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: my pleasure senpai

Comment: `pd.np.isin` - what's this?

Comment: @jpp it uses the wrapped numpy that `pandas` uses internally, such that the user doesn't need to explictly import `import numpy as np`

Comment: If you are using `.apply`, `pd.np.isin(row['CUST_NAME'], ['John','Alan'])` will be very inefficient (more-so than using .apply already is...) so just use `row['CUST_NAME'] in ['John','Alan']`